# pyspark how to convert string to date format

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, pyspark, databricks

I have a column in my dataset which is in the following format

```
Mon, 01 Mar 2021 13:23:06 +0000
```

I want to convert this to date format like yyyy-mm-dd. I tried the following solution, but the date field is NULL.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import substring
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_date
from pyspark.sql.types import DateType


df=df.withColumn('test_date', substring('test_started_at', 5,12))
df=df.withColumn('date', to_date(df.test_date, 'dd-MMM-yyyy').cast(DateType()))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Believe you can do this without using substring, just need to change the `to_date` logic -

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import to_date
from pyspark.sql.types import DateType

spark.sql("set spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy=LEGACY")

df = df.withColumn('new_date', to_date('test_started_at', 'EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z').cast(DateType()))
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked it on databricks CE (Spark 3.3) and its working if you change '-' to space in pattern:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

spark.sql("set spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy=LEGACY")

x = [(1, "Mon, 01 Mar 2021 13:23:06 +0000")]

df = spark.createDataFrame(x, schema=["id", "test_started_at"]).withColumn(
    "test_date", F.substring("test_started_at", 5, 12)
)
df2 = df.withColumn("string_to_date", F.to_date("test_date", "dd MMM yyyy")).show()
```

output:

```
+---+--------------------+------------+--------------+
| id|     test_started_at|   test_date|string_to_date|
+---+--------------------+------------+--------------+
|  1|Mon, 01 Mar 2021 ...| 01 Mar 2021|    2021-03-01|
+---+--------------------+------------+--------------+
```